# Выбор языка для быстрой разработки под Win, Linux, Mac

Tags: c#, c++, разработка-игр

Собственно, стала передо мной такая задача: сделать игру небольшого размера (в плане занимаемого места на диске) в небольшие сроки. 
Сама игра по объёму не очень большая, думал запилить на самописном движке с OpenGL.

Но вскоре понял, что `C++` и "короткие сроки" совместить довольно сложно.

Не хочется использовать JVM языки, так как под самую популярную систему для игр (Win) многим придётся скачивать JVM.

Поэтому кандидаты на роль языка:

1. C#. Поддержка на Windows "из коробки", есть возможность запустить на остальных платформах. Однако данный язык перенасыщен синтаксическим сахаром и весьма мне не нравится, поэтому использовать его я не спешу.
2. Go lang. Не пользовался, не знаю, насколько он хорош для таких целей. Намного ли он лучше (в плане скорости написания проекта) чем c++? Сырой ли он, или же вполне пригодный для написания чего-то?
3. Kotlin native. Сам язык мне нравится, однако именно native я не пробовал. Он на стадии разработки, поэтому должен быть сыроват. Однако (на данный момент) пригоден ли он для создания проектиков?
4. Haxe. Встретил такую забавную вещь, тоже не пробовал, но, по видимому, он (компилятор Haxe) умеет выплевывать исходники многих языков, а ещё компилируется  в байт-код некоторых платформ.

Больше кандидатов я не насмотрел (пока что). Хотелось бы узнать немного о целесообразности использования языков, представленных выше, в целях, в которых я хочу. Или же лучше не страдать ерундой и писать на C++?

**UPD** в целом, хочется не обсуждений в комментариях, а ответ по поводу описанных мной языков, + , может быть, ваш вариант языка, который может подойти для данной цели. Я описал причины, по которым не хочу использовать тот или иной язык, поэтому жду не переубеждения (ибо за отсутствием подходящей альтернативы вернусь к c++ или c#), а описания плюсов (или же минусов) каких-то других языков, подходящих для данной цели.

Comment: `с#` хорошо владеете? Если нет - тогда с++. Хотя если посмотреть на те же либы opengl, directx, gdiplus - там всёравно везде "мосты" на native - т.е. на либы, которые вероятнее всего на с++ писаны. Я за с++.

Comment: Начинайте писать на том языке, который знаете лучше (или у Вас есть друзья, которые с ним помогут)

Comment: @nick_n_a ну, дело скорее не во владении языком. Задача стоит скорее как "написать быстро", а не "написать быстро, и время уже пошло", так что я готов потратить время на изучение чего-то. Если не найду лучшей альтернативы, то буду писать на c++, хоть с шарпом и знаком вполне хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim лучше всего знаю яву, однако в данной ситуации это совсем не вариант(

Comment: Шарп слизан с явы. Некоторые даже намекают на плагиат. это подсказка.

Comment: @nick_n_a концептик может и да. Но по сути это попытка совместить мощь native и простоту vm языков. Попутно это дело обильно полили сахаром, и что у нас есть? Высокоуровневый язык с набором разнородных фич, в котором (лол) есть препроцессор. Поэтому он мне и не нравится. Вроде и мощный инструмент, а вроде всего по-чуть-чуть и в целом не очень.

Comment: Почему не взять какой-нибудь бесплатный С++ движок? Например, cocos2d-x. В теории там достаточно быстро можно сляпать игру. Можно использовать тот же Qt, где есть куча библиотек, которые подойдут для написании игры.

Comment: @evilnw как вы думаете, сколько времени нужно потратить на настройку cocos для нормальной компиляции? Может это и быстроч однако у меня уходило на это прилично времени. К тому же, игра, собранная вместе с движком, вряд ли будет мало весить, что (как я указал в теме) тоже является важным критерием. А так как с opengl у меня нет каких-то проблем, то для меня проще написать какой-то платформер с нуля, чем использовать движок. К тому же, из функционала мне мало что нужно.

Comment: >>лучше всего знаю яву<< c# + unity3d. Быстрее такого набора написать игрушку просто нереально). Если вес настолько критичен - используйте просто шарп. Хотя, не уверен на счёт простой совместимости с линухом и маком...

Comment: @test123 Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на первый абзац моего поста. [...небольшого размера (в плане занимаемого места на диске) ...]

Comment: слышком много требованний -  сложно... по поводу времени - я бы задействовал других людей тоже

Comment: Запилите змейку или пинг-понг в консоли - размер меньше некуда, нет заморочек с графикой, сроки минимальные.

Comment: @VTT помню, видел статью про змейку за <512 байт. Жаль, что в консоль нельзя выводить картинки, так бы наверно так и сделал=) (хотя в windows-консоль вполне можно выводить графику, жаль, что на других платформах не выйдет)

Comment: *"в консоль нельзя выводить картинки"* [ASCII-художники с вами не согласны](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB58G.gif)

Comment: @VTT выглядит клёво. Но это ведь явно работает не по принципу "каждый кадр чистим консоль, выводим все заново"? Не знаете, что можно читануть по поводу быстрого обновления текста в терминале linux, к примеру?